# Best User Interface way to update an employees Sql table from an ASP.net web application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I would like the communities opinion on the best approach to update a table from an asp.net web application.
I have an Employees table in SQL and I want to create a webform page to Insert, Update and Delete the employees from the employees table.
Not looking for code but for ideas/examples on the User Interface for this webform.
Like have a webform split into two sections one list all the employees in the table. The other sections has textboxes that represent all the fields for the employee table. When you click on one of the employees in the list all their info appear in all the textboxes on the other section.
To insert a new employee you would fill in all the textboxes then click the enter button to save the employee to the table. and so on

Would like the community to show me other better... more exciting...way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: The GridView/DetailsView combination is the "traditional" way to implement that kind of functionality in ASP.NET WebForms. I mention it even though it may not fit the "more exciting" criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jTable](http://www.jtable.org/) - a jquery plugin to perform ajax based CRUD operations.

[image]